# How to prove that every natural number not of the form $4^n(8m+7)$ can be written as $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Every natural number not of the form $4^n(8m+7)$ where $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers, can be represented as sum of three squares.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem

Comment: cite David Burton: Number theory first edition p 274. The proof is lengthy.

Answer (score 2):

This is a well-known theorem due to Lagendre, sometimes called [Legendre's Three Square Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem). Proofs are lengthly and can be found in many elementary or introductory additive number theory texts. One such proof is in Burton's Elementary Number Theory. [It's also in Gauss' classic Disquisitiones Arithmeticae].