# How do we identify if a number can be represented as the sum of squares of$ 3$ integers?

Tags: number-theory

How do we identify if a number can be represented as the sum of squares of $3$ integers?

For eg: $434 = 11^2 + 12^2 + 13^2$ but $432$ is not?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem

Comment: Useful comments [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379202)

Comment: Another [useful answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/643830/75794)